# database choice: protocoling data for hundereds to million objects

Tags: database

I am running economic simulations. hundreds, thousands or possibly millions (but not more than 30.000.000) agents = objects have to protocol data over time, the data has always the same structure. It typically is composed from a number of booleans, floats and integers, possibly arrays/list (between 5 and 100 different variables). During the simulation the database has no read access. After the simulation the data will not be changed anymore. 
For every simulation I will create a new database.
The current programming-language is python, but the choice has impact on a future project in java. Its also possible that in the future the project is run on a network. 
If it matters: the objects communicate via 0mq.
What database type and implementation should I choose?

- it needs to be open source
- good python and java APIs are indispensable

Comment: Please clarify: Do you have a starter db that you use to fill your objects with data before running the simulation? Do you ever need to write to the database (before or after the simulation)? Is db write latency an issue? Are your objects on different hosts on a network?

Comment: @DeanToader The DB is empty to begin with. After the simulation it gets only read.

Comment: DB write latency is not an issue as its irrelevant when and in which order data is written.

Comment: The objects are on the same host. But it would be interesting to hear also what would change if they are hosted distributed.

Comment: The project is now on Python and Java.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your personal needs. Millions of rows are not that much for a database.

For a start I would try Oracle 11g Express Edition. It's free and 100% compatible to the paid version, but it's limited to 11 GB of user data and 1 GB of RAM.

If you're on the open source train, check out PostgreSQL.

However, keep in mind that (most likely) you'll be bound to any database software you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Since the simulation is run on a single computer sqlite3 turned out to be a good solution. It avoids the database server which reduces complexity and increases speed.